# Android HTML 5 Video

Tags: android, html

HTML 5 video won't play on my android webview. What could be wrong. My code is as below:

```
 <video width="100%" height="60%" controls>
      <source src="bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

I have gone through related post but those didn't help me much :(

Comment: Put some text between the video tags. Does it display this text? If it does, it would indicate that your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.

Comment: I did. The text did not show. It plays on web browser but not on android webview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [nice article](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) containing the solution of your problem.
Maybe it can help you too.